# JComboBox setSelectedItem Bug or Feature?

Tags: java, jcombobox

the Original code of set selected Item is:

```
public void setSelectedItem(Object anObject) {
    Object oldSelection = selectedItemReminder;
    Object objectToSelect = anObject;
    if (oldSelection == null || !oldSelection.equals(anObject)) {

        if (anObject != null && !isEditable()) {
            // For non editable combo boxes, an invalid selection
            // will be rejected.
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getSize(); i++) {
                E element = dataModel.getElementAt(i);
                if (anObject.equals(element)) {
                    found = true;
                    objectToSelect = element;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

in my opinion the line

```
 if (anObject.equals(element)) {
```

should be

```
 if (element.equals(anObject)) {
```

Consider a Combo box displaying eg. languages
then you hav a class like

```
class Language {
     String code; // eg. "en"
     String name; // eg. "English"
...
}
```

if you add Language items to your ComboBox the toString function is used to Display an Item. In the above class the toString function would return the name. A call setSelectedItem("en") fails because

String.equals(Language) will fail because Language.toString() will return "English"

the other way round Language.equals(String) would be helping because the class Language could override

```
boolean equals(String comp) {
   return comp.equals(code)
}
```

Just for clarification, I know how to create a Combobox with the desired behaviour, my question is: is the comparison in the original code a bug or did I miss something fundamental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properly implemented [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is symmetric, meaning that there should be no difference between `anObject.equals(element)` and `element.equals(anObject)`.

You are describing a situation where the combobox model contains objects of type `Item`, but you want to select select an item by specifying an object of type `Prop`, where the value of `Prop` describes some property of `Item`.

Using technically incorrect implementation of `equals()` method you can select a combobox item by passing an instance of `Prop` instead of `Item`.

With the original code, you will have to provide broken `equals()` implementation in `Prop` class, and with your modification you will have to provide broken `equals()` implementation in `Item` class. If the `Prop` is some library class (as `String` in your example) then the former case is, of course, impossible, and i assume that the reason for your proposed modification is to allow the latter case.

I am not sure that library creators tried to prevent programmers from implementing broken `equals()` by choosing that specific `anObject.equals(element)` expression, but even if it was `element.equals(anObject)` it would still be **bad practice** to provide deliberately incorrect `equals()` implementation just for the sake of simplifying the combobox selection.

The proper way to perform selection by property would be to search the combobox data for the item with the required properties or to create a completely new instance of `Item` with the desired properties and then pass that item into the `setSelectedItem`.

If you are lucky to already use Java 8 then selecting the required item from a list is one-liner, and if not then you will have to write some boilerplate code with cycle, but at least you will have the proper `equals` implementation and clean conscience.

Answer (score 0):

To override the inherited equals method, you should pass an object as parameter and not String

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
//code goes here
}
```